# How not to use DB in the following query having a subquery

Tags: laravel, eloquent, subquery, haversine

I'm having the following function to calculate distances between two points using Haversine formula:

```
public static function getByDistance($distance)
{
    $pubsFiltered = DB::select(
        'SELECT * FROM
                (SELECT *, (6371 * acos(cos(radians(40.4169473)) * cos(radians(latitude)) *
                cos(radians(longitude) - radians(-3.7035285)) +
                sin(radians(40.4169473)) * sin(radians(latitude))))
                AS distance
                FROM pubs) AS distances
            WHERE distance < ' . $distance . '
            ORDER BY distance
            ;
        ');

    return $pubsFiltered;
}
```

This is returning an array instead of a collection, that is what I need.

If I change DB to Pub it returns an error because of the subquery where I calculate "distance" using my table "pubs".

How can I change the whole function or simply the subquery to have an instance of my Pub model?...Do I have to use set/declare variables in mysql?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: can you not just do `$result = collect($pubsFiltered);` to make it a collection?

Answer (score 1):

`$pubs = Pubs::hydrate($pubsFiltered)`

Comment: Some additional info rather than a one liner of code would help this answer massively, and would avoid it getting flagged for deletion (as this one has!).

Comment: I agree with Rob Quincey. Edit this post or it's going to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I am using this query to obtain nearby records:

```
public function scopeNearby($query, $lat, $long, $distance = 10)
{
    if($lat AND $long) {
        // 3959 for miles, 6371 for kilometers
        $distanceQuery = '(6371 * acos(cos(radians(?)) * cos(radians(geo_lat)) * ' . 
            'cos(radians(geo_long) - radians(?)) + sin(radians(?)) ' .
            '* sin(radians(geo_lat))))';

        return $query->select('*', DB::raw("{$distanceQuery} as distance"))
                ->addBinding([$lat, $long, $lat], "select")
                ->whereNotNull('geo_lat')
                ->whereNotNull('geo_long')
                ->whereRaw("{$distanceQuery} < ?")
                ->addBinding([$lat, $long, $lat, $distance], "where")
                ->orderBy('distance', "ASC");
    }
}
```

You may notice that I have used the `$distanceQuery` for both `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses. I am currently having issues when this scope is used alongside with the `paginate()` method. This might need some refactoring, but for now you can do the same.